# This pointer from internal function

Tags: javascript, scope

i have JavaScript components, that has following architecture:

```
var MyComponent = function(params)
{
    setup(params);


    this.doSomething()
    {
        // doing something
    };

    function setup(params)
    {
        // Setup

        // Interaction logic
        var _this = this; // "this" points to DOMWindow, not to created object
        $(".some-element").click(function(){
            _this.doSomething(); // it craches here, because of above
        });
    }
};
```

When something, being controlled by interaction logic, happens, sometimes i must forward execution to "public" methods of component.

In this situation, i have a problem with "this" pointer.

Sample code demonstrates it:

```
var Item = function()
{
    this.say = function()
    {
        alert("hello");
    };
    this.sayInternal = function()
    {
        _sayInternal();
    };
    function _sayInternal()
    {
        this.say();
    };
};
```

To test it,

- Create an object:

`var o = new Item();`

- This works fine:

`o.say(); // alerts "hello"`

- This crashes:

`o.sayInternal();`

I get an error:

> TypeError: Result of expression 'this.say' [undefined] is not a function.

I think, such a behaviour takes place, because _sayInternal() function is **declared** (and not assigned to object, like "this.say = function()"). This way, it is shared across all created objects and acts like a static function in C++.

Is this true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `sayInternal` is not shared between created objects. But you are right, the created objects don't have access to `sayInternal` as it is not assigned to them. This function is only local to the constructor function.

`this` always refers to the context a function is invoked in. If you call it like `func()`, then `this` refers to the global object (which is `window` in browser). If you set the function as property of an object and call it with `obj.func()`, then `this` will refer to `obj`.

If you assign a "bound" function to a variable and call it:

```
var method = obj.func;
method();
```

then `this` will again refer to the global object. In JavaScript, functions are like any other value, they don't have a special relationship to the object they are assigned to.

---

You can explicitly set the context with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var MyComponent = function(params)
{
    setup.call(this, params); // <- using `call`

    this.doSomething()
    {
        // doing something
    };

    function setup(params)
    {
        // Setup  
        // Interaction logic
        var _this = this; // "this" to new  created object
        $(".some-element").click(function(){
            _this.doSomething();
        });
    }
};
```

or in you other example:

```
var Item = function()
{
    this.say = function()
    {
        alert("hello");
    };
    this.sayInternal = function()
    {
        _sayInternal.call(this);
    };
    function _sayInternal()
    {
        this.say();
    };
};
```

---

That said, this approach to assign functions to objects is not good, because every instance will have its own  `this.sayInternal` function. So for the `Item` code above, every creation of an instance involves creating three functions too, which is a waste of memory.

Making use of [prototype inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) would be a better way:

```
var Item = function() {
};

Item.prototype = (function() {
    function _sayInternal() {
        this.say();
    };

    return {
        say: function() {
            alert("hello");
        },
        sayInternal: function(){
            _sayInternal.call(this);
        }
    }
}());
```

This way, `_sayInternal` is only created *once* and all instances inherit (refer to) the prototype, so `say` and `sayInternal` also exist only once. The "trick" with the *immediate function* makes `_sayInternal` only accessible by `say` and `sayInternal`.